# Finding File size in bit

Tags: c#

I need Exact size of File.

is there anyway to find file size in bits (not byte).

I do not want to find System.IO.FileInfo.Length and convert it to bits. Because this lose one byte information .

Comment: Why not do `myFileInfo.Length * 8`? What do you have against the `FileInfo.Length` property?

Comment: Why do you need it in bits and why can't you convert lenghts to bits?

Comment: There seems to be a hidden question here. You say that it lose one byte information. What does that mean? Are you trying to fix a bug in your application?

Comment: I think Ata is under a mistaken impression that file sizes in bytes are 'rounded' to the nearest byte, and that bits will be more accurate.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It is not possible (in any operating system that I know of) to have files whose size is not a multiple of one byte. In other words, it is not possible for a file to have a size like “3 bytes and 2 bits”. That is why all the functionality to retrieve file length returns it in bytes. You can multiply this with 8 to get the number of bits:

```
long lengthInBits = new FileInfo(fileName).Length * 8;
```

Comment: I think you hit the nail squarely on the head regarding the reason for this question.

Answer (score 2):

Well, using `FileInfo.Length` and multiplying by 8 is the most *natural* way of finding a file's size in bits. It's not like it can have a length which *isn't* a multiple of 8 bits:

```
long length = new FileInfo(fileName).Length * 8;
```

If you want to be fancy, you could left-shift it instead:

```
long length = new FileInfo(fileName).Length << 3;
```

That's not going to make any real difference though.

There are some other ways of finding the length of the file - opening it as a stream and asking the stream for its length, for example - but using `FileInfo.Length` is probably the simplest. Why don't you want to use the most obvious approach? It's like asking how to add two numbers together, saying that you don't want to use the `+` operator, but not giving a reason why...

Answer (score 1):

8 bits in a byte:

```
int numOfBits = myFileInfo.Length * 8;
```

Why do you find this to be a problem?

If you don't like the magic number:

```
public const int BitsInByte = 8;
int numOfBits = myFileInfo.Length * BitsInByte;
```